# PHP replace object property with its data

Tags: php, object

In PHP is there any way (easily) to recursively replace an objects property w/ its contents?

ie: I want to remove the "data" property recursively down through this object.  so its not a "middle man"

that way I don't have to call `$foo->data->bar->data->id` and I could just call `$foo->bar->id`

```
object(stdClass)[251]
  public 'data' => 
    object(stdClass)[224]
      public 'id' => string '1730e209-0cbf-4598-8e5a-c5ca8469e8b9' (length=36)
      public 'level_id' => string '12cada4e-0874-490e-adce-b58700244446' (length=36)
      public 'level' => 
        object(stdClass)[250]
          public 'data' => 
            object(stdClass)[252]
              ...


object(stdClass)[251]
    public 'id' => string '1730e209-0cbf-4598-8e5a-c5ca8469e8b9' (length=36)
    public 'level_id' => string '12cada4e-0874-490e-adce-b58700244446' (length=36)
    public 'level' => 
      object(stdClass)[250]
          ...
```

Comment: `$foo = $foo->data; echo $foo->bar->id;`

Comment: ya, but what if its `$foo->data->bar->data->baz->data->id`  or anything else?  thats not a reliable solution.

Comment: You can use `foreach` with (public) object properties, so you can write a recursive function

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? I'm not sure, but, anyway...

```
foreach ($foo->data as $d){
  $id = $d->bar->data->id;

  ... // do what you should here with $d children
}
```